# What's the best way to make a program update from a new PPA (when an old one is no longer maintained)?

Tags: updates, ppa

Let's say I'd like my [FreeFileSync](http://www.freefilesync.org/) to update from 6.9 (the last version available in the official PPA) to 6.15 (the last version available on the official site).

There's a proper Vivid package available in [GetDeb Apps PPA](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/getdeb_apps), *but* should I first disable [ppa:freefilesync/ffs](https://launchpad.net/~freefilesync/+archive/ubuntu/ffs) before I add this new repository to my system? Or maybe I should ppa-purge the old PPA? Won't I then lose all my FreeFileSync settings in the process? Maybe ppu-purge is too much and what I really should do is first uninstall FFS using a plain old ***apt-get remove*** (and maybe just in case backup FFS configuration files in the home directory before that), then disable the old PPA, add the new one and finally install the up-to-date package from it?

So many options. Which one's best? Please, help me get my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as my experience has gone since asking the question the simplest answer is: you just add a new PPA and let it update the package(s). The program settings stay untouched as per the usual update (because it is basically the usual update - the only thing that changes is the new source of the package(s)).